# Recipe dlib for Python-for-android

Tags: python, android, dlib

I'm trying to package an application made in python to run on Android. I'm using Dlib to identify faces and facial points on them. To package the precise application generate a recital P4a (Python-for-android) for Buildozer use. Revenue downloads dlib, but is not able to compile and copy the dependencies required for the library to work on Android. When I run Buildozer through Buildozer -v android debug deploy run, the application gets packaged and Apk is generated, however when installing on Android, it only starts and closes due to the lack of the Dlib library.

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe
import sh
from os.path import join
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from pythonforandroid.logger import shprint
from pythonforandroid.util import current_directory


class DlibRecipe(CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe):
    site_packages_name = 'dlib'
    version = '19.17'
    url = 'http://dlib.net/files/dlib-{version}.zip'
    depends = ['opencv','numpy']
    call_hostpython_via_targetpython = False

    def get_lib_dir(self, arch):
        return join(self.get_build_dir(arch.arch), 'build', 'lib', arch.arch)

    def get_recipe_env(self, arch):
        env = super(DlibRecipe, self).get_recipe_env(arch)
        env['ANDROID_NDK'] = self.ctx.ndk_dir
        env['ANDROID_SDK'] = self.ctx.sdk_dir
        return env

    def build_arch(self, arch):
        build_dir = join(self.get_build_dir(arch.arch), 'build')
        shprint(sh.mkdir, '-p', build_dir)
        with current_directory(build_dir):
            env = self.get_recipe_env(arch)

            python_major = self.ctx.python_recipe.version[0]
            python_include_root = self.ctx.python_recipe.include_root(arch.arch)
            python_site_packages = self.ctx.get_site_packages_dir()
            python_link_root = self.ctx.python_recipe.link_root(arch.arch)
            python_link_version = self.ctx.python_recipe.major_minor_version_string
            if 'python3' in self.ctx.python_recipe.name:
                python_link_version += 'm'
            python_library = join(python_link_root,
                                  'libpython{}.so'.format(python_link_version))
            python_include_numpy = join(python_site_packages,
                                        'numpy', 'core', 'include')
            python_include_opencv = join(python_site_packages,
                                        'opencv', 'core', 'include')


            shprint(sh.cmake,
                    '-DP4A=ON',
                    '-DANDROID_ABI={}'.format(arch.arch),
                    '-DANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN={}'.format(self.ctx.ndk_dir),
                    '-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL={}'.format(self.ctx.ndk_api),
                    '-DANDROID_EXECUTABLE={}/tools/android'.format(env['ANDROID_SDK']),

                    '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE={}'.format(
                        join(self.ctx.ndk_dir, 'build', 'cmake',
                             'android.toolchain.cmake')),
                    # Make the linkage with our python library, otherwise we
                    # will get dlopen error when trying to import dlib's module.
                    '-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=-L{path} -lpython{version}'.format(
                        path=python_link_root,
                        version=python_link_version),

                    '-DBUILD_WITH_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=ON',
                    # Force to build as shared libraries the dlib's dependant
                    # libs or we will not be able to link with our python
                    '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF',
                    '-DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON',

                    # Disable some dlib's features
                    '-DBUILD_dlib_java=OFF',
                    '-DBUILD_dlib_java_bindings_generator=OFF',
                    # '-DBUILD_dlib_highgui=OFF',
                    # '-DBUILD_dlib_imgproc=OFF',
                    # '-DBUILD_dlib_flann=OFF',
                    '-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF',
                    '-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF',
                    '-DENABLE_TESTING=OFF',
                    '-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF',
                    '-DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF',

                    # Force to only build our version of python
                    '-DBUILD_DLIB_PYTHON{major}=ON'.format(major=python_major),
                    '-DBUILD_DLIB_PYTHON{major}=OFF'.format(
                        major='2' if python_major == '3' else '3'),

                    # Force to install the `dlib.so` library directly into
                    # python's site packages (otherwise the dlib's loader fails
                    # on finding the dlib.so library)
                    '-DDLIB_SKIP_PYTHON_LOADER=OFF',
                    '-DDLIB_PYTHON{major}_INSTALL_PATH={site_packages}'.format(
                        major=python_major, site_packages=python_site_packages),

                    # Define python's paths for: exe, lib, includes, numpy...
                    '-DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE={}'.format(self.ctx.hostpython),
                    '-DPYTHON{major}_EXECUTABLE={host_python}'.format(
                        major=python_major, host_python=self.ctx.hostpython),
                    '-DPYTHON{major}_INCLUDE_PATH={include_path}'.format(
                        major=python_major, include_path=python_include_root),
                    '-DPYTHON{major}_LIBRARIES={python_lib}'.format(
                        major=python_major, python_lib=python_library),
                    '-DPYTHON{major}_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS={numpy_include}'.format(
                        major=python_major, numpy_include=python_include_numpy),
                    '-DPYTHON{major}_PACKAGES_PATH={site_packages}'.format(
                        major=python_major, site_packages=python_site_packages),


                    self.get_build_dir(arch.arch),
                    _env=env)
            # Install python bindings (dlib.so)
            shprint(sh.cmake, '-DCOMPONENT=python', '-P', './cmake_install.cmake')
            # Copy third party shared libs that we need in our final apk
            #sh.cp('-a', sh.glob('./lib/{}/lib*.so'.format(arch.arch)),
             #     self.ctx.get_libs_dir(arch.arch))

recipe = DlibRecipe()
```